# How to get all rows which created or updated for a specified day

Tags: oracle

I trying the count rows in Oracle database table which are created or updated for a specified day.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN), COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B 
    FROM TABLE t
)
WHERE
    SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2023-11-20 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND
    SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) < TO_TIMESTAMP ('2023-11-21 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

But I get the following error message.:

> `SQL-Fehler [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ORA_ROWSCN": ungültige ID`
>
> `Fehlerposition: line: 6 pos: 130`

What is the problem in that query?

Answer (score 1):

It is about invalid scope.

- data source - in your example - is a **subquery**
- `where` clause references `ora_rowscn` which is **supposed** to be contained in column list returned by that subquery
- but, there's no `ora_rowscn` there, is it? So, **add it**

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN), COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, ORA_ROWSCN
    FROM TABLE t                                             ----------
)                                                            -- here --
WHERE
    SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2023-11-20 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND
    SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) <  TO_TIMESTAMP ('2023-11-21 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

---

**[EDIT]** Demo in my 21cXE:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*)
  2  FROM (
  3      SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN), empno, ename, ORA_ROWSCN
  4      FROM emp t                                         ----------
  5  )                                                      -- here --
  6  WHERE
  7      SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-11-20 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  8  AND
  9      SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) <  TO_TIMESTAMP ('2023-11-21 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Comment: I get the following error, if execute the query.:
SQL-Fehler [8181] [72000]: ORA-08181: Angegebene Zahl ist keine gültige SCN
ORA-06512: in "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", Zeile 1

Comment: Query itself is OK (see demo in edited answer). Which database version do you use? If it is any version between 10.2 and 11.2, you might want to check My Oracle Support document ID 361480.1 (shortly, it says that it is *expected* as SCN must be no older than 5 days).

Comment: `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production`